# Publicar dos paginas en una misma direccion web

Tags: web, apache2, spa

Tengo una consulta sobre una aplicación de angular cualquiera.
Si tengo un dominio que puede manejar mas de una aplicación, y navego a cada aplicación a partir un una url especifica, por ejemplo:

> www.direccion.com/aplicacion1 -> para acceder a la aplicación 1
>
> www.direccion.com/aplicacion2 -> para acceder a la aplicación 2

Si estoy trabajando con angular y publico el proyecto en la aplicación 1. Como puedo hacer que mi sistema de rutas se maneje ahí dentro. Les paso a explicar:
yo publico la aplicación dentro de la carpeta "aplicacion1" y puedo accederla de la siguiente manera: `www.direccion.com/aplicacion1`

En este momento me redirecciona por defecto al componente "home" pero me modifica la url y la muestra de la siguiente manera: `www.direccion.com/home.`

Lo que yo quiero es poder trabajar en la aplicacion 1, y necesito que el sistema de rutas sea `www.direccion.com/aplicacion1/home`

Como puedo lograr eso? eh buscado por varios lados, pero no encontré lo que necesito, por eso lo estoy publicando acá.

Es en un servidor *apache2*.

Este es mi virtual host. Hice lo que me pidieron y reinicie el servidor. Pero tampoco funciona:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin email@hotmail.com

ServerName dominio.com    

ServerAlias www.dominio.com    

DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/html  
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.dominio.com [OR]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dominio.com

RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]


<Directory "/var/www/dominio.com/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny

    allow from all

</Directory>
/VirtualHost> VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin email@hotmail.com

ServerName dominio.com    

ServerAlias www.dominio.com    

DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/html/app3 
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/dominio.com/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny

    allow from all

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: La pregunta es más sobre cómo configurar Apache para servir dos SPA (Single Page Application) que sobre Angular, por lo que te he editado las etiquetas. Yo podría responderte para un servidor Nginx, pero lamentablemente no conozco Apache

Comment: para responderte debes colcar tu virtualhost, te podria ayudar un poco mas

Answer (score 0):

La opcion que necesitas conocer de apache2 es el [**Alias**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html), dicho esto, te dare un ejemplo de como debe quedar:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dominio.com 
    ServerAlias  www.dominio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/html  

    Alias /applicacion1 /var/www/aplicacion1
    <Directory /var/www/aplicacion1>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /applicacion2 /var/www/aplicacion2
    <Directory /var/www/aplicacion2>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dominio.com_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dominio.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```